# Where is JScriptTypeInfo defined?

Tags: vb6

I'm working with a WebBrowser control in VB6. I know I can access global JavaScript objects with `myWebBrowser.Document.Script.myGloblaJSObject`. How do I pass that object to another VB function? The debugger tells me it is of type `JScriptTypeInfo` but simply using that type gives me a "User-defined type not defined" compile error. Which reference defines `JScriptTypeInfo`? I'm already including references to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` and `Microsoft Internet Controls`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it late-bound (declare the argument As Object).

Or use the Object Browser to find out the type of the object. It shows you the type library at the bottom. That's the reference.